# Hive:Getting error in execution select and drop partiton hive queries in same time

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, hive-partitions

I am getting error when running two query in same time.

Here are the scenerios.

I am using AWS EMR and below is my hive table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE India (OFFICE_NAME STRING,
OFFICE_STATUS     STRING,
PINCODE           INT,
TELEPHONE   BIGINT,
TALUK       STRING,
DISTRICT    STRING,
POSTAL_DIVISION   STRING,
POSTAL_REGION     STRING,
POSTAL_CIRCLE     STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (STATE   STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE       'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION  's3a://mybucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES (  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY',   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1537781726');
```

First query:

```
SELECT count( distinct STATE ) FROM India;
```

Second query:

```
ALTER TABLE India DROP PARTITION (STATE='Delhi');
```

While running the first query, I have executed the 2nd query in same time, so I got this error in first query

```
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:271)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.next(HadoopShimsSecure.java:144)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:200)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:186)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:257)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.exception.FileDeletedInMetadataNotFoundException: File 'mybucket/India/state=Delhi/000000_0' is marked as deleted in the metadata
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.java:440)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.java:416)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getFileStatus(Unknown Source)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n2.S3NativeFileSystem2.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem2.java:227)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.getFileStatus(EmrFileSystem.java:509)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:386)
  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:372)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.ParquetRecordReaderBase.getSplit(ParquetRecordReaderBase.java:79)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:60)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:75)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:99)
  ... 15 more
```

after googled I found this link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-files-tracked.html

Is there anyway to syn metadata at runtime or 2nd query won't be execute until the first one status is completed.

Please help me to fix this issue or any suggestion, set any parameter that will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Partition path and splits are being calculated at the very beginning. Your mappers have started to read files in partition location and at the same time you dropped partition, this caused drop files, because your table is managed. This causes runtime `FileDeletedInMetadataNotFoundException` Exception.

If you still want to drop partition during reading it, try this:

If you make your table EXTERNAL then DROP PARTITION should not drop the files, they will remain and it should not cause exception, and you can remove partition location from filesystem later. Or use S3 Lifecycle policy to drop old files like described [here](https://jahed.io/2018/05/20/enforcing-retention-policies-on-s3/).

Unfortunately, already started job cannot detect that Hive partition with files was dropped and gracefully skip reading them, because Hive metadata has already been read, query plan built and splits can be already calculated.

So, the solution is to drop Hive partitions and postpone dropping files.

BTW when you add partitions when querying table, it works fine.

Comment: thnks for reply. no i can't be changed to external table.

Comment: is there anyway that drop partition query wait for complete execution of select query

Comment: @Gabber Yes, try to tune concurrency. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking#Locking-Configuration

Comment: i have tried this set hive.support.concurrency=true; but it taking long time

Comment: @Also good solution can be this: Make table EXTERNAL and drop partitions or run RECOVER PARTITIONS (or MSCK REPAIR), drop old files using AWS S3 bucket Lyfecycle policy. You upstream workflow should only put new files. Files will expire accoding to Lifecycle policy, RECOVER PARTITIONS will drop partitions without locations and add new

Comment: No, I can't do this..can be lock only metadata instead locking entire table ??

Comment: I mean that you can do RECOVER PARTITIONS before your query in the same session, not in parallel, Upstream process will put it's files, S3 will remove expired files. Your recover partitions will add/remove partitions in the same session

Comment: @Gabber Or just do the same you are doing now, but make your table EXTERNAL. Drop partition the will not drop files. And configure Lifecycle policy to remove old files.

Comment: @Gabber Updated my answer

Comment: It's a good suggestion and definitely it will work ...but data is on production mode and there is another dependency on internal table..so that's why i can't make it external table.

Comment: @Gabber What is dependency on INTERNAL table? The only difference between internal and external is DROP partition/table behavior. Everything else will work the same: same locations, same data, same queries, etc